# Integral of Dirac delta times another function with vectorial variable

Tags: integration, functions, vectors, dirac-delta, divergence-operator

I need to compute the following integral

$\int\int_{\infty}^{+\infty}{f(\vec r)\delta(\vec r) d\vec r}$

where I defined $\vec r=m_1\vec a_1+m_2\vec a_2$ with $m_1, m_2\in \mathbb{R}$

Does the integral results just $f(0)$?

In the case of single variable, let's say $x$, the integral should be:

$\int\limits_{\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x)\delta(g(x)) dx}=\frac{f(x_0)}{|g'(x_0)|}$

where $x_0$ any of the values of $x$ that makes the function $g$ be zero.

When $g(x)=x$ the result is obviously $f(x_0)$. If now I try to apply this definition to the first integral, that is setting $g(\vec r)=\vec r$, here is what I end up with:

$\int\int_{\infty}^{+\infty}{f(\vec r)\delta(\vec r) d\vec r}=\frac{f(0)}{|\vec\nabla\cdot\vec r(0)|}$

Now I think I might have a bit of confusion. Is the following expression right?

$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec r=\frac{d}{dm_1}m_1+\frac{d}{dm_2}m_2=1+1=2$

In case it was correct, the result of the first integral would be $\frac{f(0)}{2}$.

Can you help me to understand where my mistakes are?

Thank you

Comment: Is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}$ equivalent to $\iint_{-\infty}^\infty f(m_1\hat{\mathbf{a}}_1+m_2\hat{\mathbf{a}}_2)dm_1 dm_2$?

Comment: Yes, it is... I forgot to explicitly indicate the double integral.

Comment: Presumably you want to generalize $g'(x)$ to vector-valued vector functions like $g(\mathbf{r})=\mathbf{r}$ using the Jacobian, not the divergence, no? The Jacobian of $\mathbf{r}$ is the identity matrix which has determinant $1$.

Comment: I suppose that's what I want to do.... But since I use the Jacobian, how can I evaluate that integral?

Comment: I just said, replace $g'(x)$ in the formula with the Jacobian determinant.